# Generic return without generic argument

Tags: generics, rust

I am working on a course which uses automated tests. The input is given in the form of standard input and you then print the answers to standard output.

As the input usually takes the form of a bunch of values of the same type separated by spaces and I don't want to write the same code again and again I am trying to write a function to parse the input to a vector of a given type. However, my problem is that I want to a use a generic to specify what type the function will attempt to parse the data as. I don't know how to do that. My current code is:

```rust
fn std_in_to_vec(split_on: &str) -> std::io::Result<Vec<T>> {
    // read in stdin line
    let mut stdin_buffer = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut stdin_buffer).expect("could not read stdin");

    // split and read to vec
    let input: Vec<&str> = stdin_buffer.trim().split(" ").collect();

    // attempt to parse as type
    let mut parsed: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(input.len());
    for val in input {
        parsed.push(val.parse::<T>().expect("could not parse as type"));
    }

    Ok(parsed)
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't `collect` the result of `split`, which causes unnecessary memory allocations. Instead iterate directly on the `split`: `for val in stdin_buffer.trim().split(" ")` (and yes, this means that you can no longer pre-allocate the capacity for `parsed`, but this is no worse than not pre-allocating the capacity for `input` as you are doing now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just make your function generic over `T`:

```rust
fn std_in_to_vec<T>(split_on: &str) -> std::io::Result<Vec<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

You specify which version of this function you want at the **call site**. You can either make compiler infer what `T` is:

```rust
let input: Vec<i32> = std_in_to_vec()?;
```

Or specify it using **turbofish syntax**:

```rust
let input = std_in_to_vec::<i32>()?;
```

Also note that you are returning `io::Result`, but you are calling `expect` on `read_line`. That doesn't make a lot of sense. Either **propagate** the error (using for example `?` operator), or keep **panicking** on it (and in that case remove `io::Result` from returned type).

And my final comment is that `stdin` is one word.